# PowerShell + Exchange Online - Using Where-Object to filter one object against different object?

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

Really pulling my hair out on this one. I'm a bit of a beginner so apologies in advance.

I'm having trouble using the Where-Object cmdlet to basically remove external contacts from a Get-Group query in Exchange Online.

`group@domain.com` contains 4 members - `InternalUser1, InternalUser2, ExternalUser1, ExternalUser2`

This is what I have so far, and I've tried numerous different comparators (-notmatch, -notlike, -ne etc.) to no avail:

**Input**

```
$x = Get-Contact | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Identity
$y = Get-Group -Identity "group@domain.com" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Members | Where-Object {$_ -notcontains $x}
```

**Outputs**

```
$x
ExternalUser1
ExternalUser2

$y
ExternalUser1
ExternalUser2
InternalUser1
InternalUser2
```

**Desired Output**

```
$y
InternalUser1
InternalUser2
```

Excluding the Where-Object part, the outputs are correct so the issue must lie with my use of the Where-Object cmdlet. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try `-notmatch` instead of `-notcontains` ? (the latter is meant for checking elements in an array, the Where-Object uses `$_` which is a single member's DistinguishedName)

Comment: Hi Theo,

Yes, as mentioned in the post I've tried -notmatch, -notcontains, -notlike, -ne but nada! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your expanded variables contains a list of string, the following worked.

```
 $y | Where-object {$_ -notin $x}
```

Applied to your example

```
$x = Get-Contact | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Identity
$y = Get-Group -Identity "group@domain.com" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Members | Where-Object {$_ -notin $x}
```

Complete reproducible standalone example .

```
$x = @(
'ExternalUser1',
'ExternalUser2'
)

$y = @(
'ExternalUser1',
'ExternalUser2',
'InternalUser1',
'InternalUser2'
)

$y | Where-object {$_ -notin $x}
```

If this does not work, do a :

```
$x[0].GetType()
$Y[0].GetType()
```

If either Member or Identity is a complex object rather than a string, you might need to get the actual string value out of there before using the -notin